# Apache .htaccess setting error

Tags: macos, apache, .htaccess, osx-yosemite

I am trying to make a restful url through .htaccess setting in Apache (which is installed as default in Yosemite.

Here is my setting

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

When I type as 'http://localhost/~jokerham/API/user' in browser,
I get an error message as

```
Not Found

The requested URL /Users/jokerham/Sites/API/index.php was not found on this server.
```

but when I check the file in my terminal, the file exists.

```
hamdong-gyun-ui-MacBook-Air:API jokerham$ pwd
/Users/jokerham/Sites/API
hamdong-gyun-ui-MacBook-Air:API jokerham$ ls
index.php
```

Why am I getting an error with the .htaccess setting?

Comment: did you enable user homedirs in apache?

Comment: I did. When I access the url with http://localhost/~jokerham/API/index.php, it works fine.

Comment: is `user` a real directory?

Comment: user is not a real directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try your rule this way in your API directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~jokerham/API
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried but same result. "The requested URL /API/index.php was not found on this server."

Comment: I have changed the setting as follows and it worked. :: RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~jokerham/API
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php [L]

Comment: @HamDongKyun ok cool. You just needed to include the correct rewritebase depending on where your .htaccess is located.